# Execute as in SQL Server stored proc

Tags: sql-server, execute-as

I have some problem with using Execute as user in a SQL Stored proc.

I've two users called user1 and user2.
User1 has just public access in `TestDB`
User2 has execute permissions in `TestDB`
I've created a stored procedure as below:

```
USE TestDB

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Demo  
WITH EXECUTE AS 'User1'  
AS  
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[accounts]
```

when I executed sproc  under security context of User2 as below

```
use TestDB 

go 

exec dbo.usp_demo
```

it returned all records from `[dbo].[accounts]`. I assume User1 should've SELECT rights on [dbo].[accounts] to return records but here stored proc returning the results. Also the caller User2 did not have SELECT permissions on table [dbo].[accounts]. Correct me if there is anything wrong here?

Comment: [`EXECUTE AS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx): "Ownership chaining rules continue to apply. This means if the owners of the calling and called objects are the same, no permissions are checked on the underlying objects.".

Comment: " I assume User1 should've SELECT rights on [dbo].[accounts] to return records but here stored proc returning the results" what does this mean ?.

Comment: As per books online,  specified context (here User1) should've enough permissions to run the statements within the module defined. Here in this case User1 should have SELECT permissions to run stmt SELECT * FROM [dbo].[accounts] but User1 has just public access to TestDB and didn't have permissions to select data from [dbo].[accounts] table. Hope this is clear.